# How can you make buttons on a MSVS C++ CToolBar larger along with their images?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, image-manipulation

We have a touch screen, and the toolbar is too small to hit with my meaty fingers.  Is there an easy way I can have an option to make the toolbar buttons bigger and easier to hit?

So far I've attempted a few things:

```
m_toolbar.SetSizes( CSize(64,64), CSize(50,50) );
m_toolbar.SetSizes( CSize(64,64), CSize(50,50) );
m_toolbar.GetToolBarCtrl().SetButtonWidth( 64, 64 );
m_toolbar.GetToolBarCtrl().SetButtonSize( CSize(64, 64) );
```

None of these approaches stretches the images as well.  The buttons get larger, and are fully functional, but the images do not overlap the buttons the way they normally would.  I would prefer to keep a single image list for the icons, and have the images stretched to fit.

Comment: I decided to use a second TOOLBAR resource and edit the images manually. Scaling them automatically would be a nicer solution (scale from large to small) so that you wouldn't have to update two TOOLBARs whenever there is a change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At toolbar creation time, create an empty CImageList with size 64x64 (let's call it *large*). Load the original image list from resources (we call it *small*).

Iterate over each image in *small* and copy/resize it to *large*.
Then assign *large* to your toolbar. Somewhat cumbersome bui should work.

HTH,

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to make images resize with the size of the buttons. MFC applications use bmp and not vectorial images.

So you will have to supply a bmp images with the disired sizes.

You can use a CImageList and [SetImageList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74yhfwwd.aspx) to set the images but then you will have to
initialize images there with the disired size also.